# How to send parameters with a window src

Tags: javascript, php, pdf, extjs, extjs3

I have the following code:

```
new Ext.Window({
        title: 'My PDF',
        height: 400,
        width: 600,
        bodyCfg: {
            tag: 'iframe',
            src: projectparameters.service + '__pdfService.php',
            params: {
                projectparameters: projectparameters_encoded,
                featureIDs: featureIDs_encoded
            },
            style: 'border: 0 none'
        }
    }).show();
```

I am trying to send parameters to the `__pdfService.php` Is this at all possible?  I have tried using ifrmaes, but then the pdf 'encoding' is displayed instead of the actual pdf.

I cannot think that it can be such a mission do something this simple!!!

*PS:* If I query the service it returns a pdf in the window. So it works, I just want to send parameters through to make the pdf flexible

Comment: try to append to the src property something like this.  `'__pdfService.php?param1=' + encodeURIComponent(param1) + '&param2=' + encodeURIComponent(param2)` and remove the `params: {[...]}` part

Comment: Thank you, seems to work..feels like a hack though. Post it as an answer and I'll accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Update you code to and replace the param1 and param2 with your param names

```
  new Ext.Window({
            title: 'My PDF',
            height: 400,
            width: 600,
            bodyCfg: {
                tag: 'iframe',
                src: projectparameters.service + '__pdfService.php?param1=' + encodeURIComponent(param1) + '&param2=' + encodeURIComponent(param2),
                style: 'border: 0 none'
            }
    }).show();
```

Comment: Thank you. Its working. Not the way I would have liked, but it gets the job done.